# Joomla - changing user data before sending activation email

Tags: events, joomla, registration

Is it possible to change user data (username, name....) before activation email is sent to the user?
I want to use email as username, so I need to copy value of email field to the username field.
When I have used onUserAfterSave event I have been able to update username value to email value, but activation email is sent already before this event....
I have tried to use onUserBeforeSave event but without success....

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

So why dont you store e-mail as user name directly on onuserbeforesave events or similar event. So that you don't need update table & i think activation email will directly get email as user name.